# How do i fix this histogram - error and no legend

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, histogram

this may be simple and honestly, this is more a learning question as I've just started learning python this month.

The graph looks fine but theres no legend showing and its giving me: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Rectangle' and 'Rectangle'

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-deep')

no_bars = plt.bar(ind, no_no_show_prop, width, alpha=.7, label='Showed up')
yes_bars = plt.bar(ind + width, yes_no_show_prop, width, alpha=.7, label='Did not show')
bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 30)

plt.hist([no_bars, yes_bars], bins)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For debugging help, please include the full error traceback (showing where the error occurred) in your post. Please also include your plot output in the post so we can see the result. You can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with call `plt.legend`. You gave the labels above and it will work fine but you already called `no_bars` and `yes_bars` with `plt.bar`

You need to call `bins` itself at the end. So,

```
plt.hist(bins)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

should raise no error.